# How to set the build branch in teamCity

Tags: teamcity, perforce, teamcity-8.0

I'm using perforce in my project. I would like to ask, how can I set the build branch in teamcity? Right now if I want to make a build it is taking code from trunk, when I hit the "run" button it is asking me for my username/password/perforce job, I also need  to ask me for a branch name. I know that is needs to be set in the build configuration in build parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the "Run Custom Build" button to achieve it. It's located next to the "Run" button and titled with ellipsis (three dots in a row).
I might be mistaken in case of the particular VCS you're using (Perforce) though, but for me it works pretty good. When you run a custom build you can either specify the value of your %BranchName% parameter (needs to be specified in your VCS' settings) in "Parameters" tab or select a branch in "Changes" tab.
Hope this helps.